# Cannot run PayPal standard-integration js with live credentials and cannot log into sandbox

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, paypal, e-commerce

I am using PayPal standard-integration GitHub example, which is the most recent recommended example for v2 payment system by PayPal

https://github.com/paypal-examples/docs-examples/tree/main/standard-integration

When I enter my sandbox client ID and secret into .env and the same client-id index.html files, and change the amount from $100 to $1 in paypal-api.js file
It loads the PayPal payment page and it seems to work, but I don't see any money subtracted from my CC and I cannot log into the sandbox accounts using the provided emails and passwords in PayPal. I get the error `Some of your info isn't correct. Please try again.`

I don't really understand how the sandbox accounts are supposed to work. Are they for sending money or for receiving money? Am I supposed to be able to send them money from a real CC, and where does it go? or am I supposed to use another sandbox account to send to a sandbox account? Its confusing. So its easier for me to send a small amount of money from my CC to a real account
I am guessing it worked correctly and just didn't take any money from my CC that's why I don't see the transaction, but I cannot log into the sandbox account for some reason to check if it's there.
So that's the first problem, but I don't really care about sandbox accounts, I don't see any other use for them, I'd rather just use the live account if it works correctly

The second problem, when I try to enter the Live API client-ID and secret into .env and index.html I cannot load the PayPal pop up, I get the error window below and it closes immediately, I dont even have time to click to continue. None of the other 2 buttons work either.

What am I missing to use the live account? I have business enabled on my paypal. Do I need to do something else? Am I missing something? Does this example only work with sandbox and something else is needed for Live?

Thanks,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For errors when opening the window, see the Developer Tools console and Network tab. Reproduce with the Network tab cleared and open.

[Sandbox accounts](https://developer.paypal.com/dashboard/accounts) are for sending and receiving money in the [sandbox environment](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/). The two parties to the transaction must not be the same account.